# How to recover a deleted file on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, data-recovery

We have tried Boomerang but it does not find the deleted file.
The file was deleted 3 days ago. I would think it is recoverable, but Boomerang does not show it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Recoverability depends entirely on where the file was located on the hard drive and where data has been written since the file was deleted. Three days is a long time.

Comment: What file type is it?

Comment: The file is a Adobe InDesign file: .indd.

Comment: PhotoRec supports .indd.  I suggest you try out my suggestion ASAP or the file will likely become unrecoverable.

Comment: Not to lecture and I do feel your pain but this type of thing is exactly what Time Machine was built for. One situation like this is sometimes enough to get folks using it. Once you're through recovering the file with the help of the excellent advice here consider giving TM a try on an external drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) is the best tool I've found for recovering files.  It does have some baffling limitations however, like the fact that it can't recover .dmg files.  It's a command line program but still very easy to use.  And it's free :)

[This step-by-step guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) on their wiki makes it even easier.

Comment: Worked great for recovering some accidentally deleted scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Data Rescue](https://www.prosofteng.com/datarescueoptions/) software for when there isn't a backup. It's not scammy, it does the job (very well IMO), and doesn't damage drives like [some other tools](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_recovery_software) will do.

Comment: I can't recommend disk drill as I can't find a clear explanation on their web page what the free version does and when you need the pro license. It's worth it if you can't find anything else and you don't want to give Data Rescue a shot to scan for files for free before paying for a license. https://www.cleverfiles.com/help/how-to-recover-lost-files-with-disk-drill-basic/

Comment: I paid for disk drill which did not recover my files. They refused to give me a refund and are hiding behind their policy. Not a nice company to deal with. Buyer beware.

Comment: Sad to hear @SridharSarnobat I like Data Rescue since it lets you see the scan results and a couple  files before you have to pay.

Comment: That's exactly how Diskdrill is supposed to be, but it's not clear as it sounds when you're dealing with videos rather than images. I'm filing a claim with my bank right now.