# Any Way to Retrieve iPhoto pics from Time Machine deleted backups?

Tags: time-machine, photos.app, data-recovery

I'm feeling a little tearful here.  I accidentally neglected to back up properly and Time Machine deleted older backups that contained all my sons photos from infancy.  Is there any at all to recover these?  Thank you so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover a deleted file on Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that I don't believe there is a way to get those photos back. The way Time Machine works is, it will make backups of the current state of your computer, and continue doing so until space on the backup hard drive runs out. At that point, once your backup hard drive no longer has space, it begins to delete backups (oldest first) to make room for new ones.

When deleting something from a hard drive, if you immediately stop using that drive, there's some hope of getting it back since no other files have been written over where the old files were. But if Time Machine deleted old backups to make room for new ones, my guess is that they're unfortunately gone.

Time Machine SHOULD have asked you, at some point, if you were OK with it deleting old backups to make room for new ones. If you declined, it would simply stop backing up your computer until you freed up some room on the drive. If you accepted, you gave Time Machine free reign over the hard drive (which is what most people do).